# Spotify feature request

Tags: spotify

How does one submit a feature request to Spotify?

Comment: Spotify takes feature requests on the [community website](https://community.spotify.com/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe the "contact us" link on their website?

Comment: Find "contact us" link as a bit of an easter egg hunt. I managed to track down this URL which I belive is for posting ideas.

https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/idb-p/ideas_live